# Rspec forward and back slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I saw this line of code in [betterspecs](http://betterspecs.org/#subject).

```
it { expect(assigns('message')).to match /it was born in Belville/ }
```

What does the slashes before 'it' and after 'Belville' mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slashes indicate a [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html)-literal definition. It holds a **regular expression**, that can be matched againts other strings.

The example checks that the assigned instance variable `message` *matches* the regex `it was born in Belville`. In this scenario, it essentially just checks that `message` contains `it was born in Belville`. Regexes can get much more complicated than this, though.